# What would cause concrete blocks in a foundation to disintegrate?

Tags: repair, foundation, cinderblock

I had to dig out my foundation last summer because of water issues in the basement. No surprise that the drain pipes were completely clogged with a thick mat of tiny roots and mud. I was however very surprised when we started digging and found this.

The cinder block foundation had disintegrated almost entirely. Only the webbing and ends were intact. It is quite fortunate that we discovered this when we did, before that side of my garage completely gave way.

There were NO signs of termites, ants or any other pests. There were no signs of any tree or plant roots any larger than approx. 1/16" or less. (the roots you see are from a tree about 15 ft. from the wall  which was dozed down and was NOT in the ditch or near the wall).

To fix, we formed a new concrete wall 6-8" thick in front of this deteriorating wall. Then we poured and vibrated 6000psi concrete into the deterioration and made a 6-8" thick concrete wall, re-enforced with 5/8" rebar pins going into the existing wall. I should add that this was also excavated about 10-12 yrs after original construction and no deterioration was noted at that time. It has been about 20 yrs since that excavation.

What is the cause of this? Is my remedy sufficient?

The home is in N Alabama-- a very humid and wet climate.

[image: garage corner foundation]

Comment: Maybe it's only the picture but while I see deterioration what I'm surprised at is that the cinder blocks look as if they were laid sideways on the bottom three courses with the cutouts running horizontal instead of vertically. Is that the situation?

Comment: You are assuming the cinder block was satisfactory to start ; that may not be true.

Comment: @Honeydo--definitely not the situation.

Comment: @blacksmith37: that is true--but this deterioration was NOT present 10-12 yrs after laying the block.

Comment: @jwh20: you cannot see the foundation from the photo, but it is there. It is a concrete footer which is resting on sandstone. We hit rock when we had the foundation dug which unfortunately kept us from getting as deep as we desired. Solid rock ~5-6ft deep. The 'webbed' blocks seen begin 3 courses below surface. There are at least 4 courses beneath the lowest webbed one one you see (and they were OK). The photo was taken before the excavation was completed. If you look close you can see 2 courses beneath the webbed ones.

Comment: Putting together things you said in various comments: In 1988 you yourself laid these blocks, around 2000 you yourself excavated the area and found the blocks all in good shape, and in 2020 you did it again and found three adjacent rows completely missing a face but with no other damage to them and no damage to blocks above and below?  Why did you excavate in 2000 and what else did you do then?

Comment: @jay613: Why excavated in 2000?  Attempt to fix h20 leaking into the basement (~25ft upstream from this corner). What we did then in an attempt to fix the leakage issue? Installed new drainage pipe (sch40 vs thin-wall corrugated), add 6" of gravel above new drainage pipes, re-tar wall. Y to the 3 adj rows' face missing/no damage above/below. What else we did in 2000? Removed upstream gutter tie-in & made it an independent drain. Installed new sch40 drain pipe. Filled the ditch with washed gravel about 5ft deep. Add poured 6Kpsi concrete in frt of the damaged blks (& filled them with concrete).

Comment: Is it possible this was caused by some combination of your blocked drainage pipes and freezing weather?  I don't know the climate where you are, and this seems way below the freeze line for Alabama, but it's the most obvious thing and the only thing I can think of.   Could your failed drainage somehow be causing *both* water collecting around and inside these blocks (but not the ones above) and allowing that water to be exposed to freezing sometimes?

Comment: Assuming those blocks weren't just laid on their sides, it looks like the water filtering through may have "eaten" away at the structure of the concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I think the blocks were laid on there sides, possibly a small area for drainage. I know of no critter that eats concrete cinderblocks, hopefully it’s only a small area and if it is drainage may be the reason, I have had to add weep holes to foundation walls where a spring was discovered. Who knows this is not the correct way to do it and you may want to see how far this extends. This structure has absolutely no strength in an earthquake and it may need to be back filled with concrete if much wider than what we can see.

Comment: That is definitely NOT the case. I know without a doubt because my brother and I laid the blocks.We did fill with 6000psi steel reinforced concrete.

Comment: I have never seen anything like this with concrete or cinderblocks unless someone dumped muriatic or another acid that can eat concrete but even that would be a stretch.